# Need help in Ubuntu router with static IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router

I have a Linksys modem+router and Ubuntu server 12.04. My LAN networking is connecting to the internet through the Linksys router. Now I enable NAT in Ubuntu Server. Only my LAN segment is ping able from the Ubuntu Server. I need to config the Static IP to the other end of the interface.
NOW....
**Internet<=====>Linksys<====>LAN and Ubuntu Server**

What I need...
**Internet<===>Ubuntu Server<====>LAN.**

IP address details...

Linksys router = **192.168.1.1**(gateway) **122.165.67.x**(static)
Ubuntu Server  = **eth0** -122.165.67.x   **eth1** - 192.168.1.20

I think I made some mistake in eth0, setting the same IP as the Static IP.
Ubuntu Server can **ping 192.168.1.x** network but not to the internet. Which IP address I should set for the **eth0** interface

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

**Internet<===>Ubuntu Server<====>Linksys(as switch)<====>LAN.**

First, set your Linksys to operate as switch (check the manual or something). Connect your internet cable to Ubuntu directly. Then connect Linksys to the other port on Ubuntu. Configure NAT on Ubuntu properly and you get what you want.

Comment: OK I got the Idea!
Should I set the static IP directly to the Ubuntu interface?

Comment: Yes, if your internet connection requires static ip, you must set it on the Ubuntu interface.